# Synchronized Classloader calls from Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, class, weblogic, classloader

We are having a performance Issue in our project which seems to originate (at least in parts) from the way Hibernate uses the classloader. This was discovered in Java thread dumps which were taken during high load tests on our internal environment. The JVM dumped is the JVM of the Weblogic managed server which runs the application, and dumps were taken while the monitoring dashboard shows hogging threads and pending user requests.

*Example:*

```
"[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '126' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f2fe9486000 nid=0x663b waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f2faeae6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:405)
    - waiting to lock <0x000000078c0d76b0> (a weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.getConstantValue(ReflectHelper.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl$JavaConstantConverter.handleDotStructure(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:592)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl$JavaConstantConverter.visit(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:587)
```

What we can see in these thread dumps (using Samurai/TDA) is that there seem to be a great many threads at any time which are **waiting for locks on the classloader**. This classloader, provided by WLS, seems to be synchronized - which explains the locking/blocking thread pattern...

*It seems Hibernate uses the classloader to evaluate expressions in queries. So I'm not sure the classloader calls actually load any new classes.*

The problem is the number of calls to the classloader which appear to be going on all the time... At times I observed as much as 30% of the total number of threads (~30-40+ our of 130) waiting on getting a classloader lock!

--> It seems that the synchronization of the WLS classloader leads to a **very high internal overhead** when a high number of threads are trying to service a high user load (i.e. many Hibernate queries).

### Is this behavior normal or are we doing something wrong?

Right now this synchronized classloader issue seems to be the main reason which limits the throughput of our application, leading to degrading performance under heavy load. Also the problem does not go away if we scale up CPU/memory or various WLS specific pools (like EJB/JDBC connections/...) -- as it is specific to the entire JVM we run our app in.

I'd much appreciate your input on the topic.

---

P.S.

Google seemed to show that we are not the first ones to encounter this issue (e.g. [this mailing list question](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/hibernate-dev/2008-December/003548.html) or [this Oracle Support Question](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=207119821592875&id=1508444.1&displayIndex=4&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=q419sslqh_4)), but there is no real solution/explanation to this problem.

Comment: Is the getConstantValue in the stack trace in anyway significant. I could imagine this to lead to a class lock rather than an instance lock. Not that I know anything :)

Comment: Have you used the CAT tool to do any analysis? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/classloading.htm#BABHJGJJ What about class caching?

Comment: @NielsBechNielsen Hmm, the call to `getConstantValue` is occuring often but by far not in all of these blocking classloader calls.

Comment: @castling I didn't know about CAT - will definitely try it out!

Comment: This question has been moved to https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10746

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that application programmers think that `Class.forName()` and `Classloader.loadClass()` are cheap operations like a `new Object()` would be. And application servers thinks that they are a rare startup operation.

For hibernate using criteria or dynamic generated JPQL can trigger this lock contention
http://dimovelev.blogspot.dk/2015/02/performance-pitfalls-hibernate-criteria.html

Comment: Good link, thanks! Finally a clear and concise explanation of the issue. too bad that the only solution seems to be to either forgo criteria API or weblogic.

Answer (score 2):

This issue was reported multiple times on Hibernate Jira:

- [HHH-1810](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1810)
- [HHH-4959](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4959)
- [HHH-10746](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10746)
- [HHH-11246](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11246)

`Class.forName` is not free. Depending on the underlying application server, it can cause lock contention as illustrated by [Dimo Velev](http://dimovelev.blogspot.ro/2015/02/performance-pitfalls-hibernate-criteria.html).

Pierre-Hugues Charbonneau has a [similar analysis](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.ro/2014/03/classnotfoundexception-is-it-slowing.html) on this topic, which is a wonderful read as well.

The [HHH-4959](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4959) Jira issue was fixed in [Hibernate 5.2.6](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-performance-penalty-of-class-forname-when-parsing-jpql-and-criteria-queries/), and this should no longer be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

jdk1.6 java.lang.ClassLoader's loadClass is synchonized,

```
protected synchronized Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve)
throws ClassNotFoundException
```

jdk1.7 makes it each lock per className,which is more efficient

```
protected Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve)throws ClassNotFoundException{
   synchronized (getClassLoadingLock(name))
```